# How can Rails 5 Javascript use vendor assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a new Rails 5 app and am trying to use some vendor assets in my main Javascript file:

```
//= require json2.min.js
```

And the file json2.min.js is in the /vendor/javascripts/ directory.

However I get this error:

```
couldn't find file 'json2.min.js' with type 'application/javascript'
```

I am reading the documentation but cannot figure out why this doesn't just work?

Comment: Do you really need it in 2019? Most browsers today handle JSON parsing just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My stock-ish `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` says:

```
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
```

You want to put your vendor JavaScripts in `vendor/assets/javascripts` not `vendor/javascripts` for them to be found.